# Wordpress onclicking menu item, It should redirect to target div

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, css

I have menu items on my home page. When I click on an item, it should redirect to the particular div(say contact form). What I tried so far is .. I specified an Id to the div and to the menu item I gave the same Id as the URL. But the problem is, When it redirects to the Id, the div is hiding behind the header. How to fix this problem? I want to use javascript. But as I'm using WordPress I can't add an id to the menu item. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can simply use the scroll animation script

Comment: like this  $("button").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".second").offset().top-20},
        'slow');
});

Comment: Please always provide a minimal verifiable example.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go to same page div element then it is possible by giving # before the id. Use code like below
In the `menu item` part

```
<a href="#id">Contact</a>
```

In the `div` section of `Contact form`

```
<div id="id">id</div>
```

```html
<a href="#id">go to id</a>
    <div style="margin-top:2000px;"></div>
   
   
   
   <div id="id">id</div>
```

Comment: As i'm using wordpress, I can't use id to the plugin.

Comment: you can use it. By defining the `<div>` before the plugin implementation area. And you can give `id` to whole shortcodes of plugin.